# Searching with criteria on table and sub-table

Tags: postgresql

I have tables with schema below

Goals table:

```
id (int)
user_id (int)
location (string) from Google places
latitude 
longitude
gender  (int) 1 male,2 female, 3 both 
fromdate (date)
todate (date)
```

Goals Interests table:

```
_id (int)
goal_id (int)
user_interest__id (int)
```

So a user enters a goal. I'm going to be in Tampa FL US from 2016-08-18 till 2016-09-18 Looking for Male or Female (3) for Boating (interest_id 3), Cycling (interest_id 4) and Fishing (interest_id 6)

How would I write this in PgSQL? I read some docs on the joins but don't know the best way to handle the one to many on the Interests. A user can enter 1 to 3 interests when they create a "Goal"

I need to match anyone that has at least 1 similar interest, is going to be in Tampa between from & to dates and is a 1 or a 2 Gender id.

Comment: Well, you can't outsource your development to this forum. Pay someone if you don't want to read the documentation yourself.

Comment: @Ehask use join ,and

Comment: Sorry Laurenz they put me 4 months behind schedule I took the project back and trying to salvage some of what we paid for. I am rewriting most of their api code ........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three issues to consider first:

1. The logic of your app is probably that the goal and interest data of the user is first stored in the tables and then a search is done for matching goals. The below query therefore makes use of a self-join and a sub-query to find such matches.
2. You should use a `daterange` type instead of `fromdate` and `todate`. PG has some powerful operators for date ranges. So I'll assume that your table will have a `dates daterange` column.
3. You should not search on the location string but on the (longitude, latitude) pair and a maximum distance your traveler is willing to move to find that soul mate. Otherwise a perfect match in St. Petersburg or Clearwater will go unnoticed. For this you need to convert your separate `longitude` and `latitude` columns to a different type as well. You have two choices: The lightweight choice is to use the built-in `point` type and then `CREATE EXTENSION earthdistance`. Using the `<@>` operator on two points in (lon, lat) units will give a distance in statute miles. Alternatively, the much more powerful PostGIS extension can be used with `CREATE EXTENSION postgis` and then you use the `geography` type for your longitude and latitude. I'll use the first option here as it is the most straightforward and probably good enough for you. So you'll have a `loc point` column instead of longitude and latitude.

The query then becomes:

```
SELECT g2.*, g1.loc <@> g2.loc AS distance, i.interests
FROM goals g1  -- the traveler
JOIN goals g2  -- the soul mate
  ON (g2.loc <@> g1.loc) <= [[maximum distance in miles]]
 AND g2.dates && g1.dates -- dates must overlap (possibly partially)
 AND (g2.gender = 3 OR g2.gender = [[gender of user]])
JOIN (
  SELECT goal_id, array_agg(user_interest__id) AS interests
  FROM goal_interests
  WHERE user_interest__id IN (3, 4, 6) -- or whatever your interest are
  GROUP BY goal_id
) i ON i.goal_id = g2.id;
```

This query with give you all the matching data from the `goal` table, a row for each match, as well as the distance to the match and the common interests.

Comment: This is for travelers looking to find other travelers not so much dating but it will get used that way Im sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select
    g.user_id 
from
    goals g
join
    goal_interests gi on g.id = gi.goal_id 
where
    g.location = 'Tampa FL US' and
    g.fromdate >= '2016-08-18' and
    g.todate <= '2016-09-18' and
    g.gender in (1,2) and
    gi.user_interest__id in (3,4,6)
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM user_goal_interest ugi  LEFT JOIN goals g ON ugi.goal_id = g._id  LEFT JOIN users u ON g.user_id = u._id  
WHERE 
location = 'Zephyrhills, FL, United States' 
AND 
'2016-09-18' >= g.fromdate 
AND 
'2016-08-18' <= g.todate
AND 
ugi.users_interest__id IN (132,125,123)
AND
u.gender IN ('male','female')
AND 
(g.gender = 1 OR g.gender=3)`

Was the query I had written for MySQL to show them what I was looking for at the start.  Your answer would work just gave patrick the answer due to his additions